# Flume flush messages every few seconds when rolloverSize is set to 150 MB

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, flume

I have created a flume pipeline to move data from Kafka to HDFS using flume. I have set the rolloverSize to 150 MB and it gets rolledover correctly.

However I want the messages to be written to HDFS files frequently as opposed to all messages in 1 go i.e. currently the messages are kept in buffer and flushed when it reached 150MB size. Basically I want to get the msessages written to HDFS in near real time and roll over the file when 150MB is reached.

I tried setting the batchSize property but without much help.

Is the above requirement possible to implement in flume?

Answer (score 1):

hdfs.rollInterval is what you should set in your flume conf. This parameter makes Flume to flush the channel to hdfs for every specified number of seconds. So set this value to minimum interval that is feasible for your case.

Comment: However this will make very small files having very few records;thereby resulting in occupying block sizes within hdfs.

Comment: @Community : Any other ideas on how to flush messages quickly but the rollver should happen at 150MB/sec?